# Is there an implicit 'es' in 'wenn dir klar wird'?

Tags: pronoun

There is a series of German memes that open with 'Wenn dir klar wird', e.g.:

https://www.facebook.com/heuteshow/videos/10154329178480986/

> Wenn dir klar wird, was der Brexit wirklich bedeutet.

The meaning is clear:

> When it becomes clear to you, what Brexit really means.

But there doesn't seem to be a subject in that first sentence in the German. Am I right in thinking that there is an implicit 'es'? So

> Wenn es dir klar wird, was der Brexit wirklich bedeutet.

says exactly the same thing (and is grammatically 'more correct')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't (necessarily).

Reflexive constructs in German work quite well without the "es". English needs an "it" here, while German can live with or without the "es"

> Es ist mir klar, dass ...

and

> Mir ist klar, dass ...

work equally well and are both correct. The "Es" can be a help to people who struggle to find a subject in the sentence, though.

Note that *mir ist klar ...* is a similar grammatical construct than *mir ist kalt* - which would translate to "I am cold" - similarily, *mir ist klar* can be translated to "I am aware".

Comment: Should the answer then not be "yes"? The question is "implicit 'es'" and "exactly the same thing" - in my opinion you answer both with yes? Only the "grammatically more correct" in parentheses is "no".

Comment: That's a bit too simple. The "es" is a helper word for people who absolutely cannot live without a subject in a sentence. But: There are sentences without a subject that cannot be "repaired" with "es": "Hier wird Ihnen geholfen"

Comment: Please elaborate on your last comment and make it a part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With regard to your point in the comments, could you not put that as 'Es wird Ihnen hier geholfen'?